# A replacement for method = 'loess'

Tags: r, ggplot2, prediction, loess

This is where I'm at so far:

I have a data frame `df` with two columns `A` and `B` (both containing real numbers) where `b` is dependent on `a`. I plot the columns against each other:

```
p = ggplot(df, aes(A, B)) + geom_point()
```

and see that the relationship is non-linear. Adding:

```
p = p + geom_smooth(method = 'loess', span = 1)
```

gives a 'good' line of best fit. Given a new value `a` of `A` I then use the following method to predict the value of `B`:

```
B.loess = loess(B ~ A, span = 1, data = df)
predict(B.loess, newdata = a)
```

So far, so good. However, I then realise I can't extrapolate using `loess` (presumably because it is non-parametric?!). The extrapolation seems fairly natural - the relationship looks something like a power type thing is going on e.g:

```
x = c(1:10)
y = 2^x
df = data.frame(A = x, B = y)
```

This is where I get unstuck. Firstly, what methods can I use to plot a line of best fit to this kind of ('power') data without using `loess`? Pathetic attempts such as:

```
p = ggplot(df, aes(A, B)) + geom_point() +
      geom_smooth(method = 'lm', formula = log(y) ~ x)
```

give me errors. Also, assuming I am actually able to plot a line of best fit that I am happy with, I am having trouble using `predict` in a similar way I did when using `loess`. For examples sake, suppose I am happy with the line of best fit:

```
p = ggplot(df, aes(A, B)) + geom_point() +
      geom_smooth(method = 'lm', formula = y ~ x)
```

then if I want to predict what value `B` would take if `A` was equal to 11 (theoretically 2^11), the following method does not work:

```
B.lm = lm(B ~ A)
predict(B.lm, newdata = 11)
```

Any help much appreciated. Cheers.

Answer (score 10):

First , To answer your last question, you need to provide a data.frame with colnames are the predictors.

```
B.lm <- lm(B ~ A,data=df)
predict(B.lm, newdata = data.frame(A=11))

     1 
683.3333
```

As an alternative to loess you can try some higher polynomial regressions. Here I in this plot I compare `poly~3` to `loess` using `latticeExtra`(easier to add the xspline interpolation) but in similar syntax to ggplot2.(layer).

```
xyplot(A ~ B,data=df,par.settings = ggplot2like(),
       panel = function(x,y,...){
         panel.xyplot(x,y,...)
         grid.xspline(x,y,..., default.units = "native") ## xspline interpolation
       })+
  layer(panel.smoother(y ~ poly(x, 3), method = "lm"), style = 1)+  ## poly
  layer(panel.smoother(y ~ x, span = 0.9),style=2)   ### loeess
```

[image]

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer agstudy. Instead of trying higher polynomial regressions, is it not possible to use power regressions (I think these would be better suited to my data)? If possible, would you be so kind as to edit your post to show me how to do these? I would be very grateful. Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

The default `surface` for `loess.control` is `interpolate` which, unsurprisingly doesn't allow extrapolations. The alternative, `direct`, allows you to extrapolate though a question remains as to whether this is meaningful.

```
predict(loess(hp~disp,mtcars),newdata=1000)
[1] NA
predict(loess(hp~disp,mtcars,control=loess.control(surface="direct")),newdata=1000)
[1] -785.0545
```

Comment: cheers James. Yes I agree that extrapolation may not necessarily be meaningful. The reason why it seems valid in this case is that the dependence in the data looks likes it can be modeled using a power function.

Comment: Neat. Please plot us the graph on OP's dataset so we can compare for ourselves.